# Calculate the Running Total logic but first cell is coming up blank

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I need to create a running total for a report. I have tried using unbounded window function **but my first cell is coming up blank**. I need the same logic in the first cell too. Below is the initial amount I have in the table. I am using it to create the running amount as per reference number in descending order

**Initial Amount = 995**

**Logic tried**:

```
InitialAmount - SUM (Amount)  OVER(PARTITION BY ID Order By REFERENCE_NUMBER DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ) AS RUNNING_AMOUNT
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your window is empty for the first row, so the `sum()` yields `null`, which propagates to the result of the substraction.

You can work around this with `coalesce()`:

```
InitialAmount 
    - COALESCE(
        SUM (Amount) OVER(
            PARTITION BY ID 
            Order By REFERENCE_NUMBER DESC 
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
        ),
        0
    ) AS RUNNING_AMOUNT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding isnull, 0 I guess that may be a problem here.

```
InitialAmount - isnull(SUM (Amount)  OVER(PARTITION BY ID Order By REFERENCE_NUMBER 
DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ),0) AS RUNNING_AMOUNT
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually write this without the windowing clause as:

```
(InitialAmount -
 (SUM(Amount)  OVER (PARTITION BY ID Order By REFERENCE_NUMBER DESC) - Amount
 )
) AS RUNNING_AMOUNT
```

That is, it just does a regular cumulative sum (including the current row) and subtracts out the current value).